# What's the best way of comparing slices of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, slice

I attempted to compare slices of a list in Python but to no avail? Is there a better way to do this?

My Code (Attempt to make slice return True)

```
a = [1,2,3]

# Slice Assignment
a[0:1] = [0,0]

print(a)


# Slice Comparisons???
print(a[0:2])
print(a[0:2] == True)
print(a[0:2] == [True, True])
```

My Results

```
[0, 0, 2, 3]
[0, 0]
False
False
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to compare the slice _to_ here. Would you like to compare all the elements of the list to one value or comare two similarly sized slices element-wise?

Comment: @chthonicdaemon Sorry for the mishap. I want to compare two similarly sized similarly sized slices element-wise

Comment: You compare a slice with single bool value and of course you get `False` (slice will never be equal to single value). Then you compare `[0, 0]` with `[True, True]`, i.e. `[1, 1]` and again (as one would expect) you get `False`. Why are you surprised?

Comment: Your code works fine (and as expected as written) for me. Please review how [slices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since slicing returns lists and lists automatically compare element-wise, all you need to do is use `==`:

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> a[:3] == a[3:]
True
```

To compare to a fixed value, you need a little more effort:

```
>>> b = [1, 1, 1, 3]
>>> all(e == 1 for e in b[:3])
True
>>> all(e == 1 for e in b[2:])
False
```

Bonus: if you are doing lots of array calculations, you might benefit from using numpy arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> c = np.array(b)
>>> c[:3] == 1  # this automatically gets applied to all elements
array([ True,  True,  True])
>>> (c[:3] == 1).all()
True
```

Comment: Thanks!
Is there a way I can compare to fixed values? Say for example:
I want to check if first 3 characters are zero's hence something like  `a[:3] == [0,0,0]`

Comment: you can use `not any(a[:3])` to check if the first 3 values are all zero. What this is doing is checking where there are any non-zeros in the slice, then inverting the truth value.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you're trying to do exactly,

As you printed, a[0:2] is [0,0], you're trying to compare the list to a boolean which are different types so they are different

In the second one, you are comparing [0,0] to [True, True], python compares the lists element by element, and 0 evaluvates to false, so [False, False] is clearly not == to [True, True]

Could you edit your question and add what you want the code to do? I would add this in a comment but I dont have enough rep yet :)